# How to Connect Bridging Input Transformer to MacBook Mic Input

Tags: audio, sound, audio-interfaces

I am very new to audio and need some guidance. I inherited a setup where there is a mic and speakers in a meeting hall, and the audio output from that system feeds into a [bridging input transformer](https://rdlnet.com/product/tx-10b/).

I need that transformer to send a signal to the microphone input of a MacBook Air so I can use the sound to broadcast a Zoom meeting.

**I have three questions:**

1. How can I connect the output leads of that transformer to the 3.5mm
   TRRS input of the MacBook? I have [an adapter like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N9CJDVE) so far.
2. Does that transformer just do some kind of impedance matching, or
   does it actually change the sound somehow?
3. Is there some kind of device I can get that will equalize/balance
   the audio input so that if the speaker makes hard consonant sounds
   they don't make the sound level spike and get distorted?

Thanks in advance for your help!